# How function is getting called without defining in python

Tags: python, function, python-2.6

Here is the program:

```
import sys

def IndexSearchString():
    '''

    This function search a string in a password file through index and gives the result.

    :return: none
    :return type: none 
    :author: Neeraj    

    '''
    fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
    stringsrch = sys.argv[2]

    file_name = open("passwd", "r")

    for store_file in file_name:
        temp = store_file.split(":")
        search = temp[fieldindex]
        #print search 

        if stringsrch in search:
            print store_file
            #print sys.stdout.write(store_file)   
            return

#IndexSearchString()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are going to have to be more specific with what your question is.

Comment: if i remove the last line IndexSearchStrind() and runs the program, it gets excuted.

Comment: I mean how without defining the function, the programs even get executed.  I am an newbie in python.

Comment: Is that your complete file? How are you running it?

Comment: yes this is a complete file. and i am running in vim editore on an Linux OS platform.

Comment: When you execute it with the last line commented out, what happens?

Comment: My real Question: I have written program in an function and at last line i have called that function and it gives me proper output. Now if I comment that last line of function call, than also program runs. how that is possible ?

Comment: @Seth: when i comment out it gets executed. But it should not according to the logic. How can you execute an function without having a function call ??

Comment: Trying copying the code back out of the question. I suspect you've got the indentation wrong, but that docstring makes it look valid to the interpreter.

Comment: When you say the program runs, please be more specific.  Also, does the code in the question appear *exactly* as it does in vim?  Including indentation?

Comment: *Please*, tell us what "working properly" means.  If I execute the code above, with the last line commented, it will run but do nothing.  That, in my view, is working properly.  If you have some other definition you need to state it.

Comment: If it runs it means that *you didn't comment the last line*. Note that if that's your main program maybe you didn't save it(or you saved it with a different name). If that's a module it *could* be that there is an old `.pyc` around, and so the interpreter is still using the old version.

Comment: I have an problem that how the function can even get executed without defining the function call. My function is IndexSerachString() followed by the program and at last line is the function call to that function. How does it get executed as the last line is commented out

Comment: I am going to ask a yes or no question.  Please choose yes or no.  If you run the program, with the last line commented, do you see output to the screen? (This will explain to me your definition of "executed" and "working properly")

Comment: @SethMMorton Its a lost cause... just let the question fade away.

Comment: working properly means i am getting the desired output . Program is for Searching a string in password file within the index defined.

Comment: Then one of three things is happening. 1) Your indentation is incorrect (as suggested but the answer of DanielB). 2) You aren't actually saving it after you add the comment (as suggested by @Bakuriu), or 3) you are calling the function elsewhere.  Because you are right, the function body can't get run if you don't call the function.

Comment: 1. My indentation is correct. 2 I am saving a file 3i m not calling function elsewhere

Comment: Then you must have a magic implementation of python that executes function code as it defines it, because it doesn't happen when I copy and paste the code on my computer and run it.

Comment: Thank you all for replying the post. I made an identation problem after the defining the function.

Comment: @NeerajLad You need to ask a new question, not edit an existing one.

Comment: I am unable to ask . its not allowing me to ask

Comment: My question is that How do i insert data in Berkelys db in python. I need to insert Firstaname, LastName, Age and Gender into Berkelys db which are comming from form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your code is exactly as it is now in the question (including the edit by @Haidro)

The code, as you pasted it in the question, suggests your indentation was something like this:

```
def my_function():
    '''
    docstring
    '''
code_intended_for_my_function()

#my_function()
```

This would cause `code_intended_for_my_function` to be executed. This is "valid" because the `docstring` makes the definition for `my_fuction` valid (it just does nothing), then immediately executes `code_intended_for_my_function`. To test this, in the code you have, remove the `docstring` and check if you get an `IndentationError`, or just copy the code as it is currently from the question and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: I have not used the docstring

Comment: @NeerajLad Upload the file you are using somewhere so we can download and have a look at it.

Comment: Here there is no option for upload. its an text file with ':' in line

Comment: Thank you. i got the answer. Indentation problem after defining the function

Comment: @NeerajLad You should accept this answer if it solved your problem (Click the "tick" shape to the left of the answer)